# Php function include

Tags: php, mysql

So, I'm working on a dynamic forum signatures script and I alredy got it working. Now I will to make it so that only a specific user group can a specific design. 
This is the function I made.

```
function userGroup($rank)
{
    if ($rank == 38)
    { 
    return true;
    }
    else
    {
    return false;
    }       
}
```

And used it like this.

```
if ($userGroup == true) 
{
...     
}
         else echo('User with that ID doesn\'t exist in the database'); 
}
 else echo('This user hasn\'t in the specific user group');
```

But it wont work like that.
Regards, 
Lazar!

Comment: `userGroup()` is a function that takes an argument `$rank`. You're using it as a variable that probably doesn't exist. Besides, there's so many unnecessary `true`s and `false`s in your code.

Comment: your entire function can be rewritten to: `function userGroup($rank) { return ($rank == 38);}`. As mentioned earlier, you need to actually *call* your function in the script, using a variable which has the same name does not call the function.

Comment: @Tularis : nice refactor ;)

Comment: How to call a function: http://www.php.net/manual/en/functions.user-defined.php

Answer (score 0):

You made a function `function userGroup($rank)` and you are trying to call it as if its a variable `$userGroup`.  What happened to the parameter?  Your if-statement should be something like:

```
if (userGroup($var) == true) { ... }
```

You don't actually need the `== true` either:

```
if (userGroup($var)) { ... }
```

Comment: What @developerwjk said, plus your `else` statements when you "call" the function aren't nested correctly.

Answer (score 0):

you can not use a function like this. you should have a function call with valid argument like this:

```
if (userGroup($intUserRank)) 
{
...     
}
else echo('User with that ID doesn\'t exist in the database');
```

assume `$intUserRank` containing user rank.

Answer (score 0):

You function could just be like this:

```
function userGroup($rank)
{
    return ($rank == 38);
}
```

Then you would use it like this:

```
if (userGroup($some_rank)) 
{
...     
}
```